# Scoped unit names in FPC

Tags: delphi, fpc

Is it possible to port Delphi unit with a scoped name like `MyLib.Classes.pas` to FPC (ver 2.6.0) without renaming it to remove the scope prefix `MyLib.`?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. That (and other incompatibilities) were the reason for separate FMX units targeting iOS.

Comment: @TLama unfortunately not: http://bugs.freepascal.org/view.php?id=14439

Comment: @Serg, like David pointed, the link from my (now deleted) comment was to the proposals and ideas page...

Comment: If they want to have unit names as valid identifiers they probably could use dotless unit name aliases instead - just a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the moment the current FPC (2.6.0) doesn't support dotted unit names , exist a [`proposal`](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Namespaces#Suggestion_1_-_.22dotted_unit_name_notation.22) about this feature and even a  [`report`](http://bugs.freepascal.org/view.php?id=14439), but appears closed and marked as `won't fix`

Comment: Looks like one -1 for FPC for me.

Answer (score 7):

FPC's Development version (2.7.1) **does support** dotted unit name. Please see http://wiki.freepascal.org/FPC_New_Features_Trunk#Delphi-like_namespaces_units

Comment: Interesting.  Closed as Won't Fix, and now they're implementing it?

Comment: `FPC 2.7.1` has A LOOOOOONG way for it to be actually released. Try summer of 2014/2015.